# Convert Excel 2007 to Excel 97-2003 workbook automatically

Tags: java, excel, dos

I need to Convert Excel 2007 to Excel 97-2003 workbook,

i'm doing this manually by open the excel and save as Excel 97-2003 workbook
but i want it to be automated.
Is it possible

Comment: Have you looked into [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)?  (Note: I don't know much about this project, but it appears to provide an API for Excel files.)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533544/xls-convert-to-xlsx-using-java-and-poi-apache  just change the in and out variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the filespecs of the files you wish to convert in column **A** of *Sheet1* as follows:

[image]

.

Then run this small **VBA** macro:

```
Sub asdf()
    Dim s As String, N As Long, i As Long
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        s = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=s
        s = Replace(s, ".xlsx", ".xls")
        s = Replace(s, "xlsm", ".xls")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=s, _
            FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", _
            WriteResPassword:="", _
            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
            CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,It works fine but every time i need to open the workbook whenever i want to convert format......To avoid this i had use task scheduler to open the workbook .....it's also opened and convert all the files :) but it didn't close the Opened excel,Then i have tried                                  taskkill /IM excel.exe    but if i did this the conversion wont work please help to resolve this