# Error Message after creating XLSX file using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I am using apache poi to create a simple xlsx file using java as follows

```
    String date = "2014/12/29";
    XSSFWorkbook  w = ADPFidessa.createExcelWorkbook(date);
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/xlsx");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ADP_Fidessa.xlsx");
    w.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

and here is the createExcelWorkbook method

```
public static XSSFWorkbook createExcelWorkbook(String sBsnsDt) throws Exception
   {
    // create a new file
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");

    // create a new workbook
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    // create a new sheet
    XSSFSheet s = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

    // declare a row object reference
    XSSFRow r;
    // declare a cell object reference
    XSSFCell c;

    ArrayList<ADPFidessa> aDADPFidessalist=null;
    ADPFidessaDAO adpfiddao = new ADPFidessaDAO();
    aDADPFidessalist=adpfiddao.showADPFid(sBsnsDt);      

    int rownum;
    // header row and columns
    r = s.createRow(0);

    c = r.createCell(0);
    c.setCellValue("Business Date");

    c = r.createCell(1);
    c.setCellValue("ID");

    c = r.createCell(2);
    c.setCellValue("Ant");

    c = r.createCell(3);
    c.setCellValue("Sol");

    c = r.createCell(4);
    c.setCellValue("itions");

    c = r.createCell(5);
    c.setCellValue(sition");

    c = r.createCell(6);
    c.setCellValue("ffere");

    c = r.createCell(7);
    c.setCellValue("Age");

    rownum = 1;
    for (ADPFidessa di : aDADPFidessalist)
    {

     r = s.createRow(rownum);
     c = r.createCell(0);
     c.setCellValue(di.getBusinessDate());

     c = r.createCell(1);
     c.setCellValue(di.getkId());

     c = r.createCell(2);
     c.setCellValue(di.getAnt());

     c = r.createCell(3);
     c.setCellValue(di.getSol());

     c = r.createCell(4);
     c.setCellValue(di.getition());


     c = r.createCell(5);
     c.setCellValue(di.getsition());

     c = r.createCell(6);
     c.setCellValue(di.getffere());
     c = r.createCell(7);
     c.setCellValue(di.getAge());


     rownum++;
    } 

    try {
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return wb;
   }
```

the method showADPFid(sBsnsDt); returns the correct values and the output file is correctly saved. Here is the problem. When i try to open the file in MS Excel, it shows an error message

[image]

now, after clicking 'Yes', the excel file opens and all the data is there as expected. However, another dialogue box appears

[image]

the log file shows

[image]

can anyone please give any idea about this error ? How to resolve this ?

thanks

EDIT: also, here are my imports

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.util.*;
```

Comment: XSSF methods are for `.xlsx`, so it's possible you simply need to change the file's extension from `.xls` to `.xlsx` to make this error go away. Not sure though.

Comment: thanks @geert3, but that did not work ! i have made the edit in the question as well. if i create an xls file, that works just fine. if possible, can you try to create a sample dummy xlsx with say 2 rows and 2 cols ? just to see if it works

Comment: i tried, but i keep getting the error

Comment: Not sure but you're not closing the servlet's outputstream or the workbook. Try adding `w.close();` or `response.getOutputStream().flush();` after `w.write(response.getOutputStream());`

Comment: thanks, but that did not solve the issue. what do you think about the  response.setContentType("application/xlsx"); ? is it correct ?

Comment: officially it's `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` but I don't think that will be any different.

Comment: yes, i tried that as well. does not solve the problem. i even downloaded the openxml4j.jar from http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopenxml4j10betajar.htm and included it my build path. by the way, is this the correct jar ?

Comment: as long as you don't mix jars from different POI versions, and you don't get ClassNotFoundExceptions, you should be OK. Have you considered maven or similar for dependency resolution? What version of POI are you using? Tried to upgrade?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?