# error message when opening Excel file created using xlsx package R

Tags: r, export-to-excel, xlsx

I have created an Excel file using the xlsx package in R.  When I go to open the file I get an error message:
Excel found unreadable content in this workbook.
Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?

I select yes and it doesn't appear like anything is missing.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  I found another stackoverflow question about this same issue but for a different program

[Error Message after creating XLSX file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711270/error-message-after-creating-xlsx-file-using-java)

My R and OS information is below.

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

The code I have been using for the Excel file is:

```
#create excel workbook for output data
surveyresults_2015v4<-createWorkbook( )

#export catch data to output file
c_data<- createSheet(wb=surveyresults_2015v4, sheetName="catch_data")
addDataFrame(x=datag, sheet=c_data,row.names=FALSE,showNA=F )
saveWorkbook(surveyresults_2015v4, "surveyresults_2015v4.xlsx")
```

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose this without a reproducible example.  Can you provide a subset of your data that reproduces the error?

Comment: Real dataset has :1221 rows and 60 columns.  Dont know if that has something to do with it.

Comment: You overwrote the subset.  Just put it in the question above.  The size of the dataset shouldn't really matter until it gets 'very large' in which case it would be memory issues.

Comment: dput(data)
structure(list(StationID = c(201501001L, 201501002L, 201501002L, 
201501003L, 201501003L, 201501004L, 201501004L, 201501005L, 201501005L, 
201501006L), Gear = c("COMM", "COMM", "SURVEY", "COMM", "SURVEY", 
"COMM", "SURVEY", "COMM", "SURVEY", "COMM"), Totwghtpertow = c(0, 
2.58132937508837, 717.022778822871, 8.79478472723868, 754.7170022519, 
0, 750.507384562137, 5.10123602652717, 767.398718283106, 0)), .Names = c("StationID", 
"Gear", "Totwghtpertow"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: sorry - sometimes still trying to figure out this website.

Comment: The subset you provided works fine for me on my Windows machine.  You need to go through your dataset more thoroughly and figure out what data it is having trouble writing.  Try reiterating with different columns and localize where it errors.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem but in my case when I add row.names=FALSE the last column is duplicate in the saved EXCEL and the error message appear in each case whit or without row.names=FALSE. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

If you are downloading the files by a third party software from server then the transfer type maybe the issue. You may be transferring the files in  ASCII. Change the transfer type to Binary and see if this works out.

Comment: I consider this a decent "conditional" answer. I recommend however to rephrase it so that it does not contain a "?" that triggers undeserved misunderstandings. Good luck with achieving your commenting privilege. I can see you will be a valuable contributor on StackOverflow.