# How to convert .xls to .xlsx C# (.net core)

Tags: c#, excel

Good evening, recently i was looking for a free way of autonomous convertion from .xls to .xlsx without any limits, but, unfortunatly didnt find a suitable library to do that(found freespire.xls(which have limits), also easyXLS(but it has 600$ price).

Did anyone have this before?

How to convert old .xls to new one(.xlsx) that EPPlus can deal with?)

UPD: required a method which can work both at windows&linux

*Tried this, according to tutorial on SpireXLS's website*

```
// create a new excel document
Workbook book = new Workbook();

//load a document from file
book.LoadFromFile("test.xls");

//Save the file to the version you want
book.SaveToFile("test.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2007);
```

Also looking for some solution from NPOI library, maybe it could convert .xls to .xlsx(now doing that)

Comment: There's a Java example [here using POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533544/xls-convert-to-xlsx-using-java-and-poi-apache), and this can probably be easily converted to equivalent NPOI code in .NET. Or you could just use NPOI or similar to read the .xls in .NET too. There's also ExcelLibrary to read .xls in .NET.

Comment: There's an article to [Convert Excel format XLS to XLSX using C#](https://medium.com/@lockevn/convert-excel-format-xls-to-xlsx-using-c-3e1a348fca22) why don't you use that and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: @ivan-san, unfortunatly, to make this work you need to setup MS office on PC, before using this method(

Aim of that programm to be cross-platform(linux&&windows)

Comment: There's multitudes of ways to do this - what have you tried so far?  Can you [edit] in your existing `C#` code attempt?  *You don't need expensive add-ins or plugins!*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file in C# without installing Microsoft Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made this class a few months ago for this purpose based on NPOI:

```cs
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.HSSF.Util;
using NPOI.HPSF;
using NPOI.POIFS.FileSystem;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.Util;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using NPOI.HSSF.Record;
using System.Diagnostics;

/// <summary>
/// Allow to convert between xls and xlsx excel formats
/// </summary>
public class ExcelFormatConverter
{
    private Dictionary<short, ICellStyle> styleDict = new Dictionary<short, ICellStyle>();
    private IWorkbook sWorkbook = null;
    private IWorkbook dWorkbook = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the source file to the format of the destination file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sFileName">Source file to convert</param>
    /// <param name="dFileName">Destination file where the conversion is saved</param>
    public void ConvertFile(string sFileName, string dFileName)
    {
        styleDict.Clear();

        IWorkbook sWorkbook;
        using (FileStream sFileStream = new FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            sWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(sFileStream, ImportOption.All);
        }

        IWorkbook dWorkbook = null;

        string ext = Path.GetExtension(dFileName).ToLower().Replace(".", "");

        if (ext.Equals("xlsx"))
            dWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        else if (ext.Equals("xls"))
            dWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        else
            throw new Exception("Not Supported Format");

        this.sWorkbook = sWorkbook;
        this.dWorkbook = dWorkbook;

        if (sWorkbook is HSSFWorkbook)
        {
            try { HSSFOptimiser.OptimiseCellStyles((HSSFWorkbook)sWorkbook); }
            catch { }
        }

        for (short s = 0; s < sWorkbook.NumCellStyles; s++)
        {
            ICellStyle sCellStyle = sWorkbook.GetCellStyleAt(s);
            ICellStyle dCellStyle = dWorkbook.CreateCellStyle();

            //DebugCellStyle(Path.GetDirectoryName(sFileName) + @"\debug", sCellStyle);

            ConvertCellStyle(sCellStyle, dCellStyle);
        }

        if(dWorkbook is HSSFWorkbook)
        {
            try { HSSFOptimiser.OptimiseCellStyles((HSSFWorkbook)dWorkbook); }
            catch { }
        }

        ConvertWorkBook(sWorkbook, dWorkbook);
        using (FileStream dFileStream = new FileStream(dFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            dWorkbook.Write(dFileStream);
        }

        this.dWorkbook = null;
        this.sWorkbook = null;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to debug
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="cellStyle"></param>
    private void DebugCellStyle(string fileName, ICellStyle cellStyle)
    {
        string text = "---------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n";
        text += "Alignment : " + cellStyle.Alignment.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "BorderBottom : " + cellStyle.BorderBottom.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "BorderDiagonal : " + cellStyle.BorderDiagonal.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "BorderDiagonalColor : " + cellStyle.BorderDiagonalColor.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "BorderDiagonalLineStyle : " + cellStyle.BorderDiagonalLineStyle.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "BorderLeft : " + cellStyle.BorderLeft.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "BorderRight : " + cellStyle.BorderRight.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "BorderTop : " + cellStyle.BorderTop.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "BottomBorderColor : " + cellStyle.BottomBorderColor.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "DataFormat : " + cellStyle.DataFormat.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "FillBackgroundColor : " + cellStyle.FillBackgroundColor.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "FillBackgroundColorColor : " + (cellStyle.FillBackgroundColorColor == null ? "null" : cellStyle.FillBackgroundColorColor.ToString()) + "\r\n";
        text += "FillForegroundColor : " + cellStyle.FillForegroundColor.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "FillForegroundColorColor : " + (cellStyle.FillForegroundColorColor == null ? "null" : cellStyle.FillForegroundColorColor.ToString()) + "\r\n";
        text += "FillPattern : " + cellStyle.FillPattern.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "FontIndex : " + cellStyle.FontIndex.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "Indention : " + cellStyle.Indention.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "Index : " + cellStyle.Index.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "IsHidden : " + cellStyle.IsHidden.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "IsLocked : " + cellStyle.IsLocked.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "LeftBorderColor : " + cellStyle.LeftBorderColor.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "RightBorderColor : " + cellStyle.RightBorderColor.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "Rotation : " + cellStyle.Rotation.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "ShrinkToFit : " + (cellStyle is XSSFCellStyle ? "Not implemented" : cellStyle.ShrinkToFit.ToString()) + "\r\n";
        text += "TopBorderColor : " + cellStyle.TopBorderColor.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "VerticalAlignment : " + cellStyle.VerticalAlignment.ToString() + "\r\n";
        text += "WrapText : " + cellStyle.WrapText.ToString() + "\r\n";

        File.AppendAllText(fileName, text);
    }

    private void ConvertCellStyle(ICellStyle sCellStyle, ICellStyle dCellStyle)
    {
        try { dCellStyle.Alignment = sCellStyle.Alignment; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.BorderBottom = sCellStyle.BorderBottom; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.BorderDiagonal = sCellStyle.BorderDiagonal; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.BorderDiagonalColor = sCellStyle.BorderDiagonalColor; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.BorderDiagonalLineStyle = sCellStyle.BorderDiagonalLineStyle; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.BorderLeft = sCellStyle.BorderLeft; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.BorderRight = sCellStyle.BorderRight; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.BorderTop = sCellStyle.BorderTop; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.BottomBorderColor = sCellStyle.BottomBorderColor; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.DataFormat = ConvertFormat(sCellStyle.DataFormat); }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.FillBackgroundColor = sCellStyle.FillBackgroundColor; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.FillForegroundColor = sCellStyle.FillForegroundColor; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.FillPattern = sCellStyle.FillPattern; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.SetFont(ConvertFont(sCellStyle.GetFont(this.sWorkbook))); }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.Indention = sCellStyle.Indention; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.IsHidden = sCellStyle.IsHidden; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.IsLocked = sCellStyle.IsLocked; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.LeftBorderColor = sCellStyle.LeftBorderColor; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.RightBorderColor = sCellStyle.RightBorderColor; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.Rotation = sCellStyle.Rotation; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.TopBorderColor = sCellStyle.TopBorderColor; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.VerticalAlignment = sCellStyle.VerticalAlignment; }
        catch { }
        try { dCellStyle.WrapText = sCellStyle.WrapText; }
        catch { }
    }

    private short ConvertFormat(short index)
    {
        IDataFormat sFormat = this.sWorkbook.CreateDataFormat();
        IDataFormat dFormat = this.dWorkbook.CreateDataFormat();
        return dFormat.GetFormat(sFormat.GetFormat(index));
    }

    private IFont ConvertFont(IFont sFont)
    {
        IFont dFont = this.dWorkbook.CreateFont();
        try { dFont.Boldweight = sFont.Boldweight; }
        catch { }
        try { dFont.Charset = sFont.Charset; }
        catch { }
        try { dFont.FontName = sFont.FontName; }
        catch { }
        try { dFont.FontHeightInPoints = sFont.FontHeightInPoints; }
        catch { }
        try { dFont.IsItalic = sFont.IsItalic; }
        catch { }
        try { dFont.IsStrikeout = sFont.IsStrikeout; }
        catch { }
        try { dFont.TypeOffset = sFont.TypeOffset; }
        catch { }

        try
        {

            byte[] rgb = null;

            if (sWorkbook is HSSFWorkbook)
            {
                if (((HSSFWorkbook)sWorkbook).GetCustomPalette().GetColor(sFont.Color) == null)
                {
                    rgb = new byte[] { (byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255 };
                }
                else
                {
                    rgb = ((HSSFWorkbook)sWorkbook).GetCustomPalette().GetColor(sFont.Color).RGB;

                    if (dWorkbook is XSSFWorkbook)
                    {
                        if (rgb[0] == 0 && rgb[1] == 0 && rgb[2] == 0)
                            rgb = new byte[] { (byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255 };
                        else if (rgb[0] == 255 && rgb[1] == 255 && rgb[2] == 255)
                            rgb = new byte[] { (byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)0 };
                    }
                }

            }
            else if (sWorkbook is XSSFWorkbook)
            {
                if (sFont == null)
                    rgb = new byte[] { (byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255 };
                else
                {
                    XSSFColor xColor = ((XSSFFont)sFont).GetXSSFColor();

                    if (xColor == null)
                        rgb = new byte[] { (byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255 };
                    else
                        rgb = xColor.GetRgb();
                }
            }

            if (dWorkbook is HSSFWorkbook)
            {
                // Bug in NPOI black and white colors are reversed
                if (sWorkbook is XSSFWorkbook)
                {
                    if (rgb[0] == 0 && rgb[1] == 0 && rgb[2] == 0)
                        rgb = new byte[] { (byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255 };
                    else if (rgb[0] == 255 && rgb[1] == 255 && rgb[2] == 255)
                        rgb = new byte[] { (byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)0 };
                }

                dFont.Underline = sFont.Underline;
                HSSFColor color = ((HSSFWorkbook)dWorkbook).GetCustomPalette().FindColor(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);

                if (color == null)
                    color = ((HSSFWorkbook)sWorkbook).GetCustomPalette().AddColor(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);

                dFont.Color = color.Indexed;
            }
            else if (dWorkbook is XSSFWorkbook)
            {
                // Conditional Underline because of a bug in NPOI
                if (sFont.Underline != FontUnderlineType.None)
                    ((XSSFFont)dFont).Underline = sFont.Underline;

                ((XSSFFont)dFont).SetColor(new XSSFColor(rgb));
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return dFont;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the source work book to the format of the destination workbook
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sWorkbook">workbook source</param>
    /// <param name="dWorkbook">workbook destination</param>
    public void ConvertWorkBook(IWorkbook sWorkbook, IWorkbook dWorkbook)
    {
        try { dWorkbook.MissingCellPolicy = sWorkbook.MissingCellPolicy; }
        catch { }

        for (int i = 0; i < sWorkbook.NumberOfSheets; i++)
        {
            ISheet sSheet = sWorkbook.GetSheetAt(i);
            ISheet dSheet = dWorkbook.CreateSheet(sSheet.SheetName);

            try { dSheet.ForceFormulaRecalculation = sSheet.ForceFormulaRecalculation; }
            catch { }

            ConvertSheet(sSheet, dSheet);

            SheetState state = SheetState.Visible;

            try
            {
                if (sWorkbook.IsSheetHidden(i))
                    state = SheetState.Hidden;
                if (sWorkbook.IsSheetVeryHidden(i))
                    state = SheetState.VeryHidden;

                dWorkbook.SetSheetHidden(i, state);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        try { dWorkbook.SetActiveSheet(sWorkbook.ActiveSheetIndex); }
        catch { }
    }

    protected void ConvertSheet(ISheet sSheet, ISheet dSheet)
    {
        int numberOfColumns = 0;

        for(int i = sSheet.FirstRowNum; i <= sSheet.LastRowNum; i++)
        {
            try { ConvertRow(sSheet.GetRow(i), dSheet.CreateRow(i)); }
            catch { }

            try
            {
                if (sSheet.GetRow(i) != null && numberOfColumns < sSheet.GetRow(i).LastCellNum)
                    numberOfColumns = sSheet.GetRow(i).LastCellNum;
            }
            catch { }
        }

        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns;i++)
        {
            try { dSheet.SetColumnWidth(i, sSheet.GetColumnWidth(i)); }
            catch { }

            try
            {
                if (sSheet.IsColumnHidden(i))
                    dSheet.SetColumnHidden(i, true);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sSheet.NumMergedRegions; i++)
        {
            try { dSheet.AddMergedRegion(sSheet.GetMergedRegion(i)); }
            catch { }
        }

        try { dSheet.DisplayFormulas = sSheet.DisplayFormulas; }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.DisplayGridlines = sSheet.DisplayGridlines; }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.DisplayGuts = sSheet.DisplayGuts; }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.DisplayRowColHeadings = sSheet.DisplayRowColHeadings; }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.DisplayZeros = sSheet.DisplayZeros; }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.FitToPage = sSheet.FitToPage; }
        catch { }

        try { dSheet.HorizontallyCenter = sSheet.HorizontallyCenter; }
        catch { }

        try { dSheet.SetMargin(MarginType.BottomMargin, sSheet.GetMargin(MarginType.BottomMargin)); }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.SetMargin(MarginType.FooterMargin, sSheet.GetMargin(MarginType.FooterMargin)); }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.SetMargin(MarginType.HeaderMargin, sSheet.GetMargin(MarginType.HeaderMargin)); }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.SetMargin(MarginType.LeftMargin, sSheet.GetMargin(MarginType.LeftMargin)); }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.SetMargin(MarginType.RightMargin, sSheet.GetMargin(MarginType.RightMargin)); }
        catch { }
        try { dSheet.SetMargin(MarginType.TopMargin, sSheet.GetMargin(MarginType.TopMargin)); }
        catch { }

    }

    protected void ConvertRow(IRow sRow, IRow dRow)
    {
        if (sRow != null && dRow != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (sRow.RowStyle != null)
                    dRow.RowStyle = styleDict[sRow.RowStyle.Index];
            }
            catch { }

            if (sRow.FirstCellNum >= 0)
            {
                for (int i = sRow.FirstCellNum; i <= sRow.LastCellNum; i++)
                {
                    if (sRow.GetCell(i) != null)
                    {
                        try { ConvertCell(sRow.GetCell(i), dRow.CreateCell(i)); }
                        catch { }
                        try { dRow.Height = sRow.Height; }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ConvertCell(ICell sCell, ICell dCell)
    {
        if (sCell != null && dCell != null)
        {
            try { dCell.CellComment = sCell.CellComment; }
            catch { }

            try
            {
                if (sCell.CellStyle != null)
                    dCell.CellStyle = styleDict[sCell.CellStyle.Index];
            }
            catch { }

            switch (sCell.CellType)
            {
                case CellType.String:
                    try { dCell.SetCellValue(sCell.StringCellValue); }
                    catch { }
                    break;
                case CellType.Numeric:
                    if (DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(sCell))
                    {
                        try { dCell.SetCellValue(sCell.DateCellValue); }
                        catch { }

                        //short format = dWorkbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss.fff");

                        try { dCell.CellStyle.CloneStyleFrom(sCell.CellStyle); }
                        catch { }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try { dCell.SetCellValue(sCell.NumericCellValue); }
                        catch { }
                    }

                    break;
                case CellType.Boolean:
                    try { dCell.SetCellValue(sCell.BooleanCellValue); }
                    catch { }
                    break;
                case CellType.Error:
                    try { dCell.SetCellErrorValue(sCell.ErrorCellValue); }
                    catch { }
                    break;
                case CellType.Formula:
                    try { dCell.SetCellFormula(sCell.CellFormula); }
                    catch { }
                    break;
                default:
                    try { dCell.SetCellType(CellType.Blank); }
                    catch { }
                    break; 
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

The conversion can take time depending of the size of the excel file.
And it doesn't work for excel files with charts or macros.
But it's handy for styled datasheets. I made it based on [NPOI version 2.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/2.3.0)
I don't know if it works with newer version.

Feel free to use it or modify it.

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked for me, but some styles are broken =)

Anyway, thank you, will try to make it work like a charm =)